# Symfony2 session var not defined on controller

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a weird error with Symfony2 sessions that I can't explain. Sometimes some vars are not defined.

I have a controller method like this:

```php
public function controlAction ( Request $request ) {
    $now = new \DateTime();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $start = $request->get("start", "no");
    $end   = $request->get("end"  , "no");

    if ( $start === "ok" ) {
        $this->logger->info("[START]");
        $session->set("sum", 0);
        $session->set("starts_at", $now);
    } elseif ( $end === "ok" ) {
        $this->logger->info("[END]");
        $tmp = $session->get("sum", 0);
        $session->set("sum", ++$tmp);
        $session->set("ends_at", $now);
    } else {
        $this->logger->info("[OTHER]");
        $tmp = $session->get("sum", 0);
        $session->set("sum", ++$tmp);
    }

    // Checking:
    $s = $session->get("starts_at", null);
    $e = $session->get("ends_at", null);
    $this->logger->info("ON SESSION [starts_at] -> " . ((isset($s) ? $s->format('r') : '--')));
    $this->logger->info("ON SESSION [ends_at] -> " . ((isset($e) ? $e->format('r') : '--')));
    $this->logger->info("ON SESSION [sum] -> " . $session->get("sum", null));

    return new JsonResponse(array("code" => "ok"), Codes::HTTP_OK);
}
```

And then in other method:

```php
$startsAt = $session->get("starts_at", null);
$endsAt = $session->get("ends_at", null);
$this->logger->info("-- [starts_at] -> " . ((isset($startsAt) ? $startsAt->format('r') : '--')));
$this->logger->info("-- [ends_at] -> " . ((isset($endsAt) ? $endsAt->format('r') : '--')));
```

And in logs I'm getting this:

```
[2016-11-28 10:20:40] app.INFO: [START] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:40] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:40] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:40] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 0 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:41] app.INFO: [OTHER] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:41] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:41] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:41] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 1 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:42] app.INFO: [OTHER] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:42] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:42] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:42] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 2 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:43] app.INFO: [OTHER] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:43] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:43] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:43] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 3 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:44] app.INFO: [OTHER] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:44] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:44] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:44] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 4 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:45] app.INFO: [OTHER] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:45] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:45] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> -- [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:45] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 5 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:46] app.INFO: [END] [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:46] app.INFO: ON SESSION [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:46] app.INFO: ON SESSION [ends_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:46 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:46] app.INFO: ON SESSION [sum] -> 5 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:52] app.INFO: -- [starts_at] -> Mon, 28 Nov 2016 10:20:40 +0100 [] []
[2016-11-28 10:20:52] app.INFO: -- [ends_at] -> -- [] []
```

At the end, the *ends_at* var (requested six seconds latter) **is not defined**. But now is this execution, sometimes is *starts_at* var the one that is not defined.

I'm lost. Can someone shed some light?

**Edit to add more information:**

After some tests I saw that a GET request is fetched just at the same time as *controlAction* when ends_at is set, and delaying a second this request the error appear to be solved. But in the controller of that request no session object is used...

**Edit 2: More information**

If in this GET Request that happens at the same time that the last call to *controlAction* I get the *$session* and "save it" it seems to solve the error too:

```php
public function aSimpleController ( Request $request ) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->save();

    [...]
}
```

Comment: How extrange! Maybe a race condition? Where is the exact flow of execution? Can you post the code who handles sessions?

Comment: @dbardelas I don't know. Race condition it is supposed to be handled as php sessions are locked (& Symfony PdoSessionHandler issues a real row lock at database level using transactions). controlAction controller is executed once a second until the "end", and then, and only then, the other code is executed latter once when user click a button, in the middle, no session for this user is written again. Even without locks, in this "optimistic approach" ends_at "should" not be overwritten or clear. https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I saw that a GET request is fetched just at the same time as *controlAction* when *ends_at* is set.

If in this GET Request that happens at the same time I get the `$session` and "save it" it seems to solve the error.

```php
public function aSimpleController ( Request $request ) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->save();

    [...]
}
```

According to the documentation, `$session->save()` ["force the session to be saved and closed"](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/SessionInterface.php#L90)